# Counting countries read from file

Tags: arraylist, vbscript

I am trying to create an arraylist to record data in 2 columns, 1st is Country, 2nd is Count.
When I read data from a file line by line, I wish to search arraylist for country, and if found, amend count field and increase by 1. If not found, add country to country field and make count field equal 1.

When done reading file I wish to sort arraylist by either country or count field, then display results (write to file).

Any suggestions please, and I am open to other ways of doing this, but what I have found seems to suggest all my requirements can be done using arraylists.

Answer (score -1):

A [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) would be a more suitable data structure for this purpose. Store the countries as keys and increment the value.

```
Set countries = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
countries.CompareMode = vbTextCompare   'make comparisons case-insensitive

For Each value In datalist
  countries(value) = countries(value) + 1
Next
```

Sort the keys of the dictionary and write the values corresponding to the sorted keys to the output file.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thanks for your reply. I have tried this and I am getting bogged down. Here is the code  If countries.exists(country) then  countries.item(country) = countries.item(country) + 1  else  countries.add(country), 1 end if  Testing show it is finding country exists as true on first iteration(1st line read from file) but the dictionary is empty ,so I am a loss.   Any ideas?   THanks

Comment: @DenisFarrell Code becomes unreadable in comments. Please update your question with your actual code (a minimal, complete, self-contained sample). Also, why did you deviate from what I suggested? You can get creative *after* you got things to work.